# What's stopping video cards from being utilized to their full capacity on Linux?

Tags: linux, graphics

Why do video cards have better quality on Windows? Is there something about Linux that stops video cards from being utilized to their full capacity? What would it take to get the best possible graphics out of a video card on Linux?

Answer (score 5):

There is no fundamental reason for not being able to get the same quality output from graphics cards for the same hardware under Windows and Linux. However the development of software, both the drivers, and any application software, needs to be written and doing that both for Windows and for Linux just takes extra effort.

Such double effort always takes away resources or interferes with doing it just for one platform. So even if a company might gain additional hardware/software sales by making the effort, this has to be counted against possible loss of advantage if they would focus more, or exclusively, on one platform.

In the early 90's I worked mostly with Silicon Graphics (SGI) machines running their Unix variant (Irix). These were the **only** computers that could handle 3D graphics and video processing at levels acceptable for movie makers. The high-end graphics (for that time) would not work under Windows, because for the longest time Windows was not an installable option for the SGI hardware. In movies like Jurrasic Park would use SGI machines both for making the movies and [in the movie](http://www.siliconbunny.com/fsn-the-irix-3d-file-system-tool-from-jurassic-park/) itself.

Nowadays, in the gaming industry e.g., Windows is dominant in quality of output and that is just because more effort is put into that platform because of higher expected sales not because Linux could not obtain these quality levels.

However in creation of high quality graphics for movies like The Hobbit with its 48fps (whether you like it or not), the [software](https://www.sgo.es/2013/01/sgo-mistikas-unique-workflow-helps-to-produce-world-first-major-48fps-3d-feature-film-the-hobbit-an-unexpected-journey/) used is Linux based. Using Linux was the developers decision based among others on the level of graphics quality that needed to be obtained. (Disclaimer: I have been involved in providing development services for this software company, so you are right to think me biased about the quality of the graphics output).